# I am gettin warning "value is returned not all execution path" for jQuery.grep in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following line of code

```
var selectedMedId = jQuery.grep(privateVariables.medIdData, function (n) {
    if (n.DescriptionWithCode.toString().toUpperCase() === description.toString().toUpperCase()) {
        return n;
    }
});
```

I tried following also

```
 var selectedMedId = jQuery.grep(privateVariables.medIdData, function (n) {
     return n.DescriptionWithCode.toString().toUpperCase() === description.toString().toUpperCase();
 }
 });
```

And I want get rid of this warning.

Comment: Output of `$.grep` should be `true` or `false`.

Comment: Well, as you can see, in the second case you have a syntax error. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that replicates the problem. If we know what the data is and can actually see the error, it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: Where exactly do you get that warning from?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a single ID here, this should be the correct syntax:

```
var selectedMedId = jQuery.grep(privateVariables.medIdData, function (n) {
    return (n.DescriptionWithCode.toString().toUpperCase() === description.toString().toUpperCase());
})[0];

if (selectedMedId) {
    ...
}
```

Looks like your first attempt was returning an object rather than `true` or `false`, and your second attempt had one closing parenthesis too many.

The clue was in the warning, the first attempt was not always returning from $.grep, it was only returning if there was a match in n.DescriptionWithCode and description.